# What are the two stars doing in this bash script? Just negating?

Tags: bash

I was able to get an if statement with wildcard file matching done thanks to [this reference](http://www.ducea.com/2009/03/05/bash-tips-if-e-wildcard-file-check-too-many-arguments/).  However, I don't understand what exactly the double asterisks are doing here:

```
files=$(ls /tmp/*.cache 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
if [ **"$files" != "0"** ]
then
echo "Cache files exist: do something with them"
else
echo "No cache files..."
fi
```

Is it just negating the statement, so in this case it's saying 'if number of files not not equals 0'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asterisks shouldn't be there. It looks like the author meant to bold `"$files" != "0"` but accidentally inserted literal asterisks. The line should read simply:

```
if [ "$files" != "0" ]
```

<sub>(If you run the script with them there they will be interpreted as globs. If there were a file in the current directory that started with `0` such as `0.txt` or `0123-foobar` then `"0"**` is a wildcard pattern that would match those file names [`"0"**` here is equivalent to `0*`]. On the other hand if no such files exist then it'll become the literal string `0**`, equivalent to `'0**'`.</sub>

<sub>In either case, the most likely result is that the two strings will always compare unequal.</sub>

<sub>Needless to say, checking if a variable is `0` or not shouldn't vary based on what files happen to exist in the current directory.)</sub>

Comment: You can also mention `globstar`, but I fear they were put there as a means of emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

Running with `set -x` shows that this condition is evaluated as `'[' '**0' '!=' '0**' ']'` essentially making the condition always true.

The `**` should be removed, they look like an error.